# How to add a new screen to your React project as css files are conflicting?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

If some properties have been defined for the same selector (element) in different style sheets, the value from the last read style sheet will be used.
So how to add a new screen to my react project and define their style.css differently??

Comment: use the `!important` keyword and read about CSS priorities

Comment: Using `!important` is a last resort. Creating a selector with higher specificity is the better way to go. [This documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) will help you.

If you want help that's more specific to your project, post the relevant portion of your CSS file as well as your React component.

Comment: I want to use to different css files for to different web pages (in React) but now I have to take care of priority order and everything. Is there a way that that my style.css files for two different web pages don't merge??

Comment: Can anyone help me?